# Linq to entities: replace OrderByDescending/First with Max?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following query that I'm using to extract data from an SQL database using Entity Framework.

```
var result = ViewHelper.Create<Keyword>().Find(query, inc => inc.Page)
    .GroupBy(g => g.PageId)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(o => o.Volume).First())
    .OrderByDescending(r => r.Volume)
    .Select(r => new LinkDto(
        currentUrl.ToAbsolute(r.Page.Path),
        r.Term.HighlightExcept(meta.ReservedWords)));
```

If you ignore the first line (which is our own repository stuff), the next 3 lines are the important stuff.

What I'm trying to do is group the rows by `PageId`, selecting the one with the largest `Volume`.

Then, from the grouped data, I reorder again by `Volume` to return the overall list in `Volume` order.

It does seem to produce the required result, but as we all know, not all Linq statements perform the same way, and I'm convinced it can be improved upon.

The first thing that springs to mind is that the `OrderByDescending/First` elements could be replaced by a `Max` - unfortunately I haven't been able to get it to hang together syntactically.

Can this statement be improved upon.

For completeness, here's the table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Keyword] (
    [Id]     SMALLINT      NOT NULL,
    [Term]   VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [Volume] INT           NOT NULL,
    [PageId] SMALLINT      NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Keyword] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [AK_Keyword_Keyword] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Term] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Keyword_Page] FOREIGN KEY ([PageId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Page] ([Id])
);
```

Comment: "Improved" -- in what way?

Comment: @GertArnold - well, I read on another SO thread that Max is much more performant than using OrderBy/First, so I guess than was my major area of concern.

Comment: Ideally, your LINQ should translate to SQL, and in SQL orderby+first versus Max depends on indexes and the plan may end up the same. In what context was `Max` more performant?